# How do I monitor an applications memory usage while debugging in VS 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am searching for a possible memory leak in my c# application. I am not sure which part is actually causing the issue. Is there a way for me to view how much memory is actually being assigned as I perform various operations with my application while I'm debugging it using Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/04/04/net-memory-allocation-profiling-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: Thank for pointing out this tool.I'm trying out the Performance Wizard now. Hopefully it will allow me to find my memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the max-ram column in task-manager (tskmgr.exe)

[image: MAX-RAM howto]

[image: Max-ram vs RAM]